How does the Ferengi economy work?
In Star Trek - the Federation is a post-scarcity socialist (for want of a better world) utopia, that has abandonded the concept of money.
This makes sense in light of the existence of replicators and other technlogy - the modern day economy couldn't possibly work in a world with plenty of supply and little demand. How can you have demand for goods / commodities / etc. when the replicators can produce anything you want and as much of it as you want? So they can abandon the concept of money - and once people aren't tied down to day-to-day jobs trying to put food on the table, they are free to pursue their own goals - improving themselves and the world around them.
However, the Ferengi seem to have something equivalent to our modern day money-based economy. They engage in trade and try to exploit opportunities and people to make profit wherever they can. But seeing as presumably they have access to replicators and all the rest of the technology too, what exactly do they trade in? What are the goods & commodities? OK latinum itself can't be replicated, but all the stuff it would be used to buy can! Who would agree to be exploited and oppressed while working in (say) Quark's bar when, really, they don't need the job!?

Does this answer your question? Don't replicators make the Ferengi rather pointless? The second answer there is thorough.

"Very well, thanks for asking." —Grand Nagus Quark
